# MKMapSnapshotter renders borders white

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I am using `MKMapSnapshotter` to create a screenshot of a map which I then display in an `UIImageView`.

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(imageView)

let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
options.region = mapView.region
options.size = mapView.frame.size

let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
    imageView.image = snapshot?.image
}
```

However, the resulting image seems to have ugly white lines instead of the standard thin red country (and federal) borders.

[image: Simulator screenshot of image view]

Is there any way I can make the screenshot look like the original map?

[image: Simulator screenshot of map view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a Simulator issue. I see the same issue on Simulator, but on real iOS 8 and iOS 9 devices snapshots contains proper country borders.